# Could you please correct my sentences?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, writing-critique

Could you please correct my text ?

虽然我会说一口流利的法语，但是我想说一口流利的汉语。

我的职业 是律师。

律师 的责任很大，因为他必须解决严重得实情。然后压力大。

可是在巴黎 律师逐渐增加。 因此招聘越来越少。

Answer (score 2):

The a versions are acceptable I'm told. 2 needed no changes.

1. 虽然我会说一口流利的法语，但是我想说一口流利的汉语。(illogical 虽然。。。但是。。。)
   1a. 我已经会说一口流利的法语，我希望我的汉语能像我的法语一样流利。
2. 我的职业是律师。
3. 律师的责任很大，因为他必须解决严重得实情。然后压力大。
   3a. 作为律师，我的压力很大，责任很重，因为律师总得解决严重的事情。
4. 可是在巴黎 律师逐渐增加。 因此招聘越来越少。
   4a. 在巴黎律师的数量越来越多，因此工作机会越来越少。

Comment: Little tip on 4a: 的数量 could be removed, 'cause 律师起来越多 implies the increment of the quantities of lawyers.

Comment: You're right! I didn't see that. Brevity is best!

Comment: so this is an chinese native who answer you

Answer (score 1):

虽然我会说一口流利的法语，但是我想说一口流利的汉语。

我的职业是律师。

律师的责任很大，因为他必须解决严重**得实情**。然后压力大。

律师的责任很大，因为他必须**处理**严重**的案件**。然后压力**很**(1)大。

可是在巴黎，律师逐渐增加。因此**招聘**越来越少。

可是在巴黎，律师逐渐增加。因此**工作机会**越来越少。

(1) [很 - Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%E5%BE%88)